# JavaFX - Want to show DB data in card layout design which can be added dynamically during runtime

Tags: javafx, layout, plugins, cardlayout, gluon

I am now creating an `JavaFX` application which should do the following.

1. Fetch data from a Database table and show it in a small `tableView` in `JavaFX` application.
2. User select a row and make some changes and click on submit.
3. The updated data should be reflected in a card layout.
4. Repeating the above should add another card and continuous.

I have researched and got some idea about showing in table and modifying the data.

However I stuck in creating a card layout.

**QUESTION** 
Please help me to create a class or any `jar` file that would help me create a card Layouts like below to show the modified database table data.

I did research a lot but only getting `html\css` card layout but not with `JAVAFX`.

**Sample screenshot**
[Card Layout Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bry42.jpg)

Comment: If you are using `TableView` here is an example -> https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX.

Comment: I am not sure whether I can achieve the required layout in TableView as it can hold only single line of detail in each cell. In the given example also we have only single detail in each cell however my requirement is little different. I want to keep several containers in different places inside a card and the card should repeat whenever I am selecting a row in the table.

Comment: Actually in the picture, some cells have more than one detail.  The first column has an image and two labels.

Comment: You could also use a ListView to accomplish this.

Comment: Sure let me try. Thanks for your reply